# Prestashop 1.6 different taxes but same retail price

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

We want our Prestashop 1.6 to have the following setup:

1. Delivery to Austria and Germany
2. Austria has 20 % regular sales tax, Germany 19 % (reduced: 10 %, 7 %)
3. We want both all our customers see the exact same price

Example: A product costs 10 € net, retail price for **both countries** then needs to be **12 €** (20 %). For german customers we only need to pay 19 %, so we would have an extra revenue of 0,084 €

This is a very common solution here, because prices hardly differ between the two countries and therefore it is most convenient, for the seller and the buyer, to see the exact same price.

I would prefer **setting up prestashop** to handle it without any modifications. One solutions would be to set up price rules on each and every product (Different base price for germany). But as we will handle thousands of products, this would be quite a hassle.

Q: Do you know any options in prestashop itself to display the same gross prices? If not, what solution would you recommend (e.g. Module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the easiest way is to create a specific price for each country.

Say the price shall be 20 €

The net value would be (20 % tax in Austria): 16.666667
Specific Price for Germany (19 %) with new base price: 16.8067227

Tax rule: 20% AT, 19% DE